# How to get the inserted id of create() method in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the last inserted id made from `create()` eloquent in laravel.

Here's my laravel code

```
   $product = ProductModel::create([
        'prodCode' => $prodCode,
        'prodTitle' => $dataProducts->prodTitle,
        'prodDesc' => $dataProducts->prodDesc,
        'attachment' => "images/products/".$attachment,
        'prodSize'  => $dataProducts->prodSize,
        'prodCategory' => $dataProducts->prodCategory,
        'prodPrice' => $dataProducts->prodPrice,
        'created_by' => auth()->user()->id
    ]);
```

I will use this last inserted id for another query with the same function.

Is it possible to do it with this way of saving data, or do I need to convert this code to another efficient way?

Comment: if you are doing multiple inserts at the same time I suggest using `insert` method to insert it all at once. It is efficient than doing multiple requests to MySQL for the insert. But to fetch the ID you will have to make a second MySQL call fetching the last inserted row, Otherwise, the query you have shown is incorrect and `create` method returns back the full Model data so you can access `id` using it,

Answer (score 2):

The create function of a model returns new record.
Very easily:

```
$product = ProductModel::create([...]);

// last inserted id
$lastInsertedId = $product->$idField;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well in this case your are doing right !

use `print_r($product->id)` to see the last inserted id if the field name is `id`